# How to use linked chart in fusion chart

Tags: asp.net, fusioncharts

I am trying to use a linked chart using pop up window in fusion chart but i can't seem to figure out to modify my code based on some examples i saw online using the linked chart using pop up window.  My code currently opens a new page but i rather use a pop up window.  Here is the example i saw online but not able to translate this and modify my code:

```
<set label="2004" value= "37800" link="P-nameOfWindow, resizable=no-showChildChart.asp"/>
```

and here is my code which opens a new page:

```
 while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Construct the chart data in XML format
               xmlStr.AppendFormat("<set label='{0}' value='{1}' link='{2}'/>", reader["cat_name"].ToString(), reader["Total"].ToString(), Server.UrlEncode("DrillDown1.aspx?AppName=" + reader["cat_name"].ToString()));

            }
```

Comment: I guess there is a confusion with the term 'pop-up' window. `p-' in FusionCharts opens a Web Browser's pop-up window (exactly like http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html) and not a window-like HTML container as we find in jQuery dialog or Ext-JS window.

Comment: i just figured out.. you put P- infront of the file name.....Server.UrlEncode("P-DrillDown1.aspx?AppName="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put   P-    infront of the file name and that will do it..

```
..Server.UrlEncode("P-DrillDown1.aspx?AppName="...
```